# Having problems displaying multiple charts on a page

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm getting the error failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item, I think it's because my loadCharts function is being called before the gamesArray is being populated therefore on the template, it can't see the id. But I'm not 100%.

I've tried await async, doesn't work, I've tried calling this.loadCharts() after eaching through the games. I've tried an *ngIf to not load the chart before there are games, but I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

This is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { _ } from 'underscore';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { GameService } from '../../services/games.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sports-cards',
  templateUrl: './sports-cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sports-cards.component.scss']
})

export class SportsCardsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  currentPage = 1;
  chart: [];
  gamesArray = [];
  test = [];

  constructor(
    public games: GameService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGames();
  }

  async getGames() {
    const game = await this.games.getAllGames(this.currentPage);
    _.each(game.games, (gameData) => {
      this.gamesArray.push(gameData);
    });
    this.loadCharts(this.gamesArray);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadCharts(this.gamesArray);
  }

  onPageChange(pageData) {
    this.currentPage = pageData;
    this.games.getAllGames(this.currentPage).then(game => {
      console.log(this.currentPage);
      // this.gamesArray = game;
    });

  }

  loadCharts(gameData) {
    _.each(gameData, (games) => {
      console.log(games);
      console.log('hello');
      this.chart = new Chart(games.id, {
        type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: [games.homeTeam.teamName, games.awayTeam.teamName],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: games.homeTeam.teamName + ' Vs ' + games.awayTeam.teamName,
            backgroundColor: [games.homeTeam.schoolPrimaryColor, games.awayTeam.schoolSecondaryColor],
            data: [games.homeTeam.totalBets, games.awayTeam.totalBets]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: games.homeTeam.teamName + ' Vs ' + games.awayTeam.teamName
        }
      }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 float-right" >
  <!-- <div *ngIf='loading'  class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status"></div>
  </div> -->
  <!-- <div *ngIf="!loading"> -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 card-background"
            *ngFor="let game of gamesArray"
          >
            <div class="card-surround shadow-sm">
              <div>
                  <h2>{{game.homeTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                  <h2>{{game.awayTeam.teamName}}</h2>
                  <canvas id="{{game.id}}"></canvas>
                  <hr>
                  <p>{{game.gameTime}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <ngb-pagination
  class="d-flex justify-content-end"
  [collectionSize]="gamesArray.length"
  [(page)]="currentPage"
  [maxSize]="5"
  [pageSize]='6'
  (pageChange)='onPageChange($event)'
  size="sm"
  [rotate]="true"
  [ellipses]="false"
  [boundaryLinks]="true"
  ></ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

It's giving me an error Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item for each of the games that I'm creating. The games show up, just not the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You've done almost. :D
It is better to execute all contents related to the displayed item in `ngAfterViewInit ()` to prevent DOM error.
Because sometimes your DOM doesn't exist when you display something.

Based on your template html, you have spinner.
So,

1. Show spinner - `ngOninit()`
2. Get data - `ngOninit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()`
3. Display data - `ngAfterViewInit()`
4. Hide spinner - after displaying.

---

Here is further information about `ngOninit()` :  [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>   Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

So, If you have any `@Input` decorator, `ngOninit()` is a moment to get it from template html, but not a time to show something. just good time to check properties.
Also, please remind, the constructor is not a part of angular's lifecyle.
And be careful, `*ngIf` will destroy your DOM, it is not good for hiding your component.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still cannot seem to get my charts to load, but I'm wondering if it's a lifecycle problem or if it's something to do with the array. There is no more error however, so I think I may be getting closer.